# Spring DI having two constructors at the same time

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, multiple-constructors

This is an anti pattern, but I am curious what will actually happen.

If you explicitly define a no-args constructor and a constructor with an autowired parameter, how exactly will spring framework initialize it?

```
@Service
class Clazz {

    private MyBean myBean;

    public Clazz(){}

    @Autowired
    public Clazz(MyBean myBean){
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

On top of above answers, if there is single constructor declared without @autowire, spring uses same constructor for injection.

If there multiple constructors, then Spring uses constructor which is @autowired.

Mentioned in Spring Doc https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation

> As of Spring Framework 4.3, an @Autowired annotation on such a
>   constructor is no longer necessary if the target bean only defines one
>   constructor to begin with. However, if several constructors are
>   available, at least one must be annotated to teach the container which
>   one to use

Answer (score 1):

The constructor marked by `@Autowired` will be used by spring. You can validate this by running the following code.

```java
public class Main {
  @Component
  static class MyBean {}

  @Service
  static class Clazz {
    private MyBean myBean;

    public Clazz(){
      System.out.println("empty");
    }

    @Autowired
    public Clazz(MyBean myBean){
      this.myBean = myBean;
      System.out.println("non-empty");
    }
  }

  @Component
  @ComponentScan("my.package")
  private static class Configuration {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(Configuration.class);
    ctx.refresh();
    ctx.getBean(Clazz.class);
  }
}
```

The code prints `non-empty`.